# INNER JOIN SQL with DateTime return multiple record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
Group    RecDate                oData
---------------------------------------
123      2022-03-20 02:00:00    F1xR
123      2022-03-21 02:30:00    F1xF
123      2022-03-22 05:00:00    F1xN
123      2022-03-15 04:00:00    F2xR
```

From the table above, I want to get the `MAX` date `group by` 2 char from `oData` field. Then I wrote a query like this:

```
SELECT a.Group, MAX(a.RecDate) RecDate, LEFT(a.oData, 2) oDataNo
INTO #t1
FROM TableData a
GROUP BY a.Group, LEFT(a.oData, 2)

SELECT * FROM #t1
```

Then, the result should be:

```
Group    RecDate                 oDataNo
--------------------------------------------
123      2022-03-22 05:00:00     F1
123      2022-03-15 04:00:00     F2
```

From the result above (`#t1`), I want to join with the `TableData` to get the `RIGHT` character (1 digit) from `oData` field. So I `INNER JOIN` the `#t1` with `TableData`. The JOIN field is `RecDate`. But it is strange that the result isn't what I want.

The query like:

```
SELECT RIGHT(a.oData,1) oDataStat, b.* 
FROM TableData a 
INNER JOIN #t1 b ON a.RecDate = b.RecDate
```

The wrong result like:

[image]

The result should be:

```
Group    RecDate                 oDataNo       oDataStat
-----------------------------------------------------------
123      2022-03-22 05:00:00     F1            N
123      2022-03-15 04:00:00     F2            R
```

Am I doing wrong approach?

Please advise. Really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @DaleK, just add my 'wrong result' query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query you provided returns the data you desire. However its cleaner to do it in a single query e.g.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
        , RIGHT(a.oData,1) oDataStat
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(a.oData, 2) ORDER BY RecDate DESC) rn
    FROM TableData a
)
SELECT [Group], RecDate, oData, oDataStat
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY RecDate;
```

returns:

| Group | RecDate | oData | oDataStat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-03-15 04:00:00 | F2xR | R |
| 123 | 2022-03-22 05:00:00 | F1xN | N |

Note: Your query as posted doesn't actually run due to not escaping `[Group]` - you should ensure everything you post has any errors removed first.

Comment: Hi @Dale K, Please check the picture on my question. I just add more information. Why the final result has 16 rows after joining the table?

Comment: anyway, your answer is perfect. I'll follow your approach. Cheers mate, really appreciated.

Comment: Your join failed because you had lots of duplicate RecDate values... its not a unique join condition.